# xfce4 - Completely disabling sound for notifications?

Tags: sound, xfce, notification

I'm using `Xfce4` under `Ubuntu 20.04.4` (*i.e.*, it's `Xubuntu`).

I would like to totally and completely disable all notification sounds, always. However, I want all other sound to be enabled as normal.

I have not been able to find any configuration settings that control notification sounds. Am I missing something, or am I just out of luck?

**PS**: In `Settings=>xsettings`, the `EnableEventSounds` and `EnableInputFeedbackSounds` items are not set. Nonetheless, I am still getting sounds for all my notifications.

Thank you in advance for any ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this has nothing to do with `Xfce4`.

The sound-based notifications are coming from `Google Chrome`. In Google's infinite "wisdom" (ha-ha!), they made it impossible to disable sound within `Chrome` notifications. Those `Chrome` notifications themselves can be disabled, but if they are turned on, then the sound comes with them. That sound goes through the normal audio channel, and so it is not possible to disable that very annoying `Chrome` notification sound without also disabling all other audio.

So ... I see now that this question has nothing to do with `Xubuntu` nor with `Xfce4`.

I'm very sorry for the false alarm.